# How do scopes and thread locals work in (V8's) C++?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I am intrigued by how V8's scopes work.

How can a scope object on the stack find other scope objects and contexts further up the stack?

Digging into how HandleScopes worked I found that they rely on thread locals.  This has left me wondering how these work in C++, I've found the implementation but still don't feel I understand what's going on.

*api.cc* -- HandleScope looks for the current Isolate

```
HandleScope::HandleScope() {
  i::Isolate* isolate = i::Isolate::Current();
  API_ENTRY_CHECK(isolate, "HandleScope::HandleScope");
  v8::ImplementationUtilities::HandleScopeData* current =
      isolate->handle_scope_data();
  isolate_ = isolate;
  prev_next_ = current->next;
  prev_limit_ = current->limit;
  is_closed_ = false;
  current->level++;
}
```

*isolate.cc* -- static method looks for the current isolate as thread local

```
  // Returns the isolate inside which the current thread is running.
  INLINE(static Isolate* Current()) {
    const Thread::LocalStorageKey key = isolate_key();
    Isolate* isolate = reinterpret_cast<Isolate*>(
        Thread::GetExistingThreadLocal(key));
    if (!isolate) {
      EnsureDefaultIsolate();
      isolate = reinterpret_cast<Isolate*>(
          Thread::GetExistingThreadLocal(key));
    }
    ASSERT(isolate != NULL);
    return isolate;
  }
```

*platform.h* -- calls a low level method to retrieve thread local

```
  static inline void* GetExistingThreadLocal(LocalStorageKey key) {
    void* result = reinterpret_cast<void*>(
        InternalGetExistingThreadLocal(static_cast<intptr_t>(key)));
    ASSERT(result == GetThreadLocal(key));
    return result;
  }
```

*platform-tls-win32.h* -- the magic happens

```
inline intptr_t InternalGetExistingThreadLocal(intptr_t index) {
  const intptr_t kTibInlineTlsOffset = 0xE10;
  const intptr_t kTibExtraTlsOffset = 0xF94;
  const intptr_t kMaxInlineSlots = 64;
  const intptr_t kMaxSlots = kMaxInlineSlots + 1024;
  ASSERT(0 <= index && index < kMaxSlots);
  if (index < kMaxInlineSlots) {
    return static_cast<intptr_t>(__readfsdword(kTibInlineTlsOffset +
                                               kPointerSize * index));
  }
  intptr_t extra = static_cast<intptr_t>(__readfsdword(kTibExtraTlsOffset));
  ASSERT(extra != 0);
  return *reinterpret_cast<intptr_t*>(extra +
                                      kPointerSize * (index - kMaxInlineSlots));
}
```

- How exactly is this last method working?
- How does it know where to look?
- What is the structure of the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view `InternalGetExistingThreadLocal` as an inline version of `TlsGetValue` WinAPI call.

On Windows in user mode `fs` segment register allows code to access Thread Information Block (TIB) which contains thread specific information, for example Thread Local Storage structures.

Layout of TIB and the way TLS is stored inside TIB is exposed in DDK (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block for quick overview of the TIB layout).

Given this knowledge and ability to read data from TIB via `__readfsdword(offs)` (which is equivalent of reading `dword ptr fs:[offs]`) one can directly and efficiently access TLS without calling `TlsGetValue`.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I'm wondering whether it has any advantage over C++11's thread_local -- besides being available in older compilers.